# Insert a React component inside markdown without MDX

Tags: reactjs, markdown

How can I insert `<MyReactComponent />` inside a markdown paragraph?

1. I needs it to be universal -- ie, the markdown might be parsed by a non-react-aware program in which case it should be ignored.
2. The react component doesn't need arguments (I don't need to pass data to it, just need to indicated in the markdown where it goes)

I'm using NextJS with data from a headless CMS like this:

```js
import marked from 'marked';
import MyReactComponent from './myComponent';

function Content({markdownContent}){
  return(
    <div className="content">
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: marked(markdownContent) }} />;
      // squirt MyReactComponent into appropriate place above...
    </div>
  )
}
```

I'm intentionally using "marked" libary as it's light and basic... I would prefer not to use something heavy like mdx, or complicated... I just need to replace placeholders of some type in the markdown.

Comment: Show as an example... What kind of HTML output you expect after using React Component with state

Comment: The react component (MyReactComponent) is a stateless pure component. Which is why I don't think I need to resort to MDX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an `useEffect` hook to update the dom with `ReactDOM.render` if you have an element with a unique identifier in your markdown.

Here is a proof of concept:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import marked from "marked";

const MyComponent = () => <span>⭐</span>;

const markdownContent = `
# MyComponent

Testing
`;

function App() {
  const [initialized, setInitialized] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const el = document.getElementById("mycomponent");
    if (el) {
      ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, el); // you can pass props as usual
    }
    setInitialized(true);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div
      style={{ opacity: initialized ? 1 : 0 }}
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: marked(markdownContent) }}
    />
  );
}
```

By default, `marked` will include an id attribute when emitting headings. That's why I am using a heading as a placeholder for the React component. The trick is to know how `marked` generate Ids.

You can play around with this CodeSandbox:

[image: Edit insert-a-react-component-inside-markdown-without-mdx]

Comment: Slick. So this renders the page, then after the initial paint, adds the element. Nice. Won't this cause a flash / shifting of elements? Ideally, I'd like to do it before the initial paint to minimize elements dancing around on the screen...

Comment: You are right about the behavior. To minimize elements dancing around, you can set a state `initialized` and set the `div`'s opacity to be 0 if its value is false. Update it to `opacity: 1` after the React components are rendered. I have updated the answer as well as the CodeSandbox to add this behavior.